# Pushing key-value pairs and using them without indices

Tags: javascript

Can I somehow push the key:vale pairs to a JavaScript array so that I can later use them without indices even if I don't know what order I'll grab them in? I mean, such code would work:

```
var test = [];
test.push({key1: 5});
test.push({key2: 7});

console.log(test[0].key1);
```

But let's say I don't always receive the keys in that order and would like the last line to just be `console.log(test.key1);`, without the need to index it. Can I somehow push the pairs in such a way that later I only need to specify the key for which I want a value, and not an index under which it resides?

Comment: Do you want to still be able to reference test elements by index? Do you need test to be indexed both by number and by key?

Comment: You should start with reading a basic introduction to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...

```
var test = {};
test.key1 = 5;
test.key2 = 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of push, use an object and assing key1 to that like this: `test.key1 = 5`

but now it can't work as array